# How do I build Boost libraries on Code::Blocks (Windows)?

Tags: c++, boost

Ugh, I'm tired. All of my searches on the matter have been in vain. No matter how many solutions I find, I just cannot find a way to build Boost's libraries.

So, I can simply throw the 'boost' root directory into Code Block's 'include' and skip building the majority of libraries. How do I, then, build separately the non-header-only libraries?

Please, mind you that I'm a complete layman towards .bat, cmd, all this stuff. Even if anything I tried of the supposed solutions I've found already actually could work, I just cannot make head or tails of anything that is actually instructed.

Man, I just want to be able to use boost::thread's. :I

Comment: Do you know how to reassign the compiler that Code Blocks uses? Download [this MinGW distribution](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html), it comes with boost pre-built. In regards to *"mind you that I'm a complete layman towards .bat, cmd, all this stuff"*, fix that.  Learn to use your command line shell, there are mountains of information out there on the subject.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Well, here are more problems. I've followed the steps in the website, but Code::Blocks even after this doesn't recognize this new MinGW.

Comment: Have you tried following the [Boost Getting Started Guide](http://www.boost.org/more/getting_started/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How do I, then, build separately the non-header-only libraries?"

If you are using MinGW for example as your compiler choice then open up a command prompt,  navigate to the boost root directory that you downloaded/extracted and run the bootstrap.bat command in the following manner:

> bootstrap.bat mingw
>
> b2.exe

Running the bootstrap command will generate the MinGW-related library files (defaulting to the stage/lib subdirectory) that you will need to link to within Code::Blocks, which will include the one you needed for Boost.Threads for example:

[image]

And then in CodeBlocks you will need to

1. Set the location of the Boost root directory in the Search
2. Select the Linker tab and set the location of the library files
3. Select the Linker Settings tab add the necessary library names eg

See this link for more screenshots and explanations:

http://www.technical-recipes.com/2014/configuring-codeblocks-to-use-the-boost-libraries/

Comment: It has been a long time since I asked this question and I have already since understood a lot more about compilers and Code::Blocks, but this is exactly what a noob like the me of that time would have needed. Screenshots are the way.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the guide: [BoostWindowsQuickRef](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=BoostWindowsQuickRef), but the first half may be a bit confusing and outdated.

- unpack boost into a separate directory of you choice (i.e `C:\boost_1_52_0`, **don't** just throw it into the code::blocks include dir)
- make sure you can run gcc from your windows command line:

  ```
  C:\> gcc --version
  gcc (GCC) 4.6.2
  ```

  If this step fails, you have to add `<mingw installation dir>\bin` to your path environment variable:

  ```
  c:\> PATH=%PATH%;C:\PathToMinGW\bin
  ```
- run bootstrap with gcc as argument to build the boost.build engine with gcc:

  ```
  C:\boost_1_52_0> bootstrap.bat gcc
  ```
- run bjam and specify the toolset, in this case also gcc, to build the libraries:

  ```
  C:\boost_1_52_0> b2.exe toolset=gcc
  ```
- Follow the guide [Add Boost to an existing project in Code::Blocks](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=BoostWindowsQuickRef#Add_Boost_to_an_existing_project_in_Code%3a%3aBlocks)  on how to setup code::blocks for boost.

Comment: `toolset` is a Boost.Build feature, not a b2 option. As such, it should _not_ be prefixed with `--`. +1 otherwise.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward It says gcc is not a command when I type 'bootstrap.bat gcc'

Comment: @Mutoh Does entering `gcc --version` at the command line give the same error? If that's the case, you have to add the path of mingw's bin directory to your PATH environment variable as described in step 2. Try looking for a MinGW folder or search for a `gcc.exe` if you have trouble locating it. If i recall correctly, the default folder is C:\MinGW which would make C:\MinGW\bin what you'll have to add to the PATH environment variable.